# Getting Magnific Popup to work with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, magnific-popup

I'm new to using both RequireJS and Magnific Popup, and I was wondering if anyone had successfully gotten them to play nice together. If so, what was the basic structure of your code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First setup an emtry point in your html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script data-main="entrypoint" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.15/require.min.js"></script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Then in entrypoint.js you can configure jquery and magnific popup:

```
require.config({
  paths : {
    jquery : '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min',
    magnificpopup : 'path/to/magnific-popup.min',
  },
  shim: {
    'magnificpopup': ['jquery']
  }
});

require([ 'popuptest' ], function(popuptest) {
  popuptest.show();
});
```

Finally, on popuptest.js we can open a youtube popup like this:

```
define(['jquery', 'magnificpopup'], function($, magnificpopup) {
  return {
    show: function() {
      $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
            src: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btPJPFnesV4'
        },
        type: 'iframe',
        iframe: {
          cursor: null, 
          titleSrc: function(item) {
            return 'Video title';
          },
          patterns: {
            youtube_short: {
              index: 'youtu.be/',
              id: 'youtu.be/',
              src: '//www.youtube.com/embed/%id%?autoplay=1'
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.